# input column based on conditional statement pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two Pandas data frames and wish to insert day and week columns from DF2 values in DF1 where the dates match. e.g. for example below, day - 4 and week - 1 would be extracted from DF2 row 1 and inserted to all of the day and week columns in DF1.

**DF 1**

```
montgomery  year   date        day     week
0.0         2016  04/01/2016
0.0         2016  04/01/2016
0.0         2016  04/01/2016
0.0         2016  04/01/2016
```

**DF 2**

```
date       day  week
04/01/2016    4   1
05/01/2016    5   1
06/01/2016    6   1
```

I have looked into using the numpy conditional statements but haven't reached a solution, thanks

Comment: does `df1.combine_first(df2)` work

Comment: it's unclear from your example if your dates are datetimes or strings and also the date format in your second df shows short year format can you clarify this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
#if empty columns in DF1, remove them
DF1 = DF1.drop(['day','week'], axis=1)

#convert columns to datetimes
DF1.date = pd.to_datetime(DF1.date)
DF2.date = pd.to_datetime(DF2.date)

print (pd.merge(DF1,DF2, how='left', on='date'))
   montgomery  year       date  day  week
0         0.0  2016 2016-04-01    4     1
1         0.0  2016 2016-04-01    4     1
2         0.0  2016 2016-04-01    4     1
3         0.0  2016 2016-04-01    4     1
```